# PHP ajax post data truncated

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I am getting issue of my post data get truncated while internet speed is slow. In ajax I am passing base64 data of image and additional 2 fields for test purpose. In ajax file I have written code to print all POST data in file. When internet speed is normal its working fine and print all data of post in file. But if I change speed from Network panel to fast 3g / slow 3g then data truncates after some character. Please see below code and screenshot.

**index.php**

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getBase64(file) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = function () {
    var img = reader.result;
    var data = {
     'fname':"test",
     'img':img,
     'lname':"test1"
    }

    $.ajax({
   url: "ajax.php",
   data: data,
   method: 'POST',
   // timeout: 500000,
   // contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
 }).done(function(result) {
   console.log(result);
 }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, chk) {
    console.log( "error" );
    console.log( jqXHR );
    console.log( textStatus );
    console.log( chk );
  });
   };
   reader.onerror = function (error) {
     console.log('Error: ', error);
   };
}
function submit_form() {
var file = document.querySelector('#files > input[type="file"]').files[0];
getBase64(file); 
}
</script>
```

```html
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// var_dump(extension_loaded('suhosin'));
?>
<form id="files"> 
 <input type="file" name="img">
 <button type="button" id="submit" onclick="submit_form()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**ajax.php**

```html
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);




 
 $myfile = fopen("check_response.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
 $txt = json_encode($_POST);
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
 fclose($myfile);
?>
```

[image]

Comment: what should the file ending look like? the marked area in your screenshot looks fine

Comment: maybe you should put `reader.readAsDataURL(file);` after the onload bind?

Comment: @Alex its trucated base64 data

Comment: well how do you know its truncated? the other `data` fields arent there in the `$_POST` / file?

Comment: @Alex Because I have compared data passed in request and written in file. After some character base64 data truncated. Also if you note in file it must be end with 'lname' field. Which working while its normal internet speed but while its slow speed, its truncate

Comment: have you tried putting `reader.readAsDataURL(file);` after the onload bind?

Comment: @Alex Yes tried. But its not working